# the meaning of "Better off for it" and pronoun "they" from Stephen Hawking's article

Tags: pronouns, books

The quote is:

> But we should have been wary of answering back (to the questions of aliens), until we have develop a bit further. Meeting a more advanced civilisation (aliens from other planets), at our present stage (at the current stage of the human beings), might be a bit like the original inhabitants of America meeting Columbus. I don't think they were better off for it.

In the last sentence, does the pronoun "they" refer to all humans? or "original inhabitants of America"?

Comment: *I don't think they (the original inhabitants of America) were in a better position as a result (of meeting Columbus)*. The phrase *be better off* is in the dictionary.

Comment: *Syntactically* speaking, the referent of ***they*** is ambiguous. But *semantically*, it would be perverse in the extreme to suppose Hawking would have been suggesting that the *aliens* might be worse off if humanity responded to their signals. And obviously ***they*** in the parallel "American colonisation" scenario can only refer to ***the original inhabitants***, since ***Columbus*** is a singular noun (and this *isn't* a suitable context for "singular they").

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Stephen Hawking WARNING: Aliens could DESTROY us if we find Them**, an article from the  [UK - Express](https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/1032729/stephen-hawking-warning-alien-destroy-earth-aliens-discovery-breakthrough-listen)

I believe your sentence "Hawking doesn't think (the fate of) humans will be better [off]" by a visit from aliens is correct. Hawking was part of *Breakthrough Listen* – a group similar to SETI in the U.S. which scan the stars in the hope of receiving a message from space (aliens). “But we need to be wary of answering back until we have developed a bit further" and are prepared (defense etc) for a visit.  He compared how the native American were overrun by the arrival of European explorers.

Answer (score 6):

The "they" Hawking refers to is the native Americans, not humans.  I agree it's a little ambiguous but given the placement of the sentence and the fact it's in past tense there's enough evidence that Hawking is not referring to a human encounter with aliens since purportedly, that has not yet occurred.